# How can we get the current selected item from the Dropdown Search Package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I am using this package
https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search

I have a dropdown inside a form I made, when a user selects an item, I would like to get the value of the selection and assign it to a variable. I've read some docs but they are quite hard to understand in regards to getting the value out. As far as I understood, the SelectedItem property is only to set a starting selection. How can I get the selected item from the dropdown?

```dart
 DropdownSearch<String>(
                  mode: Mode.MENU,
                  showSearchBox: false,
                  showSelectedItems: true,
                  items: const [
                    'Item 1',
                    'Item 2',
                    'Item 3',
                  ],
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Items',
                  ),
                ),
```

In my above code, I'm not understanding how I should get the selected item, I am uploading the selected item to Firestore.

Comment: Can you add your example code, please?

Comment: @SalihCan I have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an example for you, please check it

```dart
 DropdownSearch<String>(
                  mode: Mode.MENU,
                  showSearchBox: false,
                  showSelectedItems: true,
                  items: const [
                    'Item 1',
                    'Item 2',
                    'Item 3',
                  ],
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Items',
                  ),
                  onChanged: (String selectedValue) {
                    yourVariable = selectedValue; // you should change this line according to your own
                  },
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [onChanged](https://pub.dev/documentation/dropdown_search/latest/dropdown_search/DropdownSearch/onChanged.html) property for [DropDownSearch](https://pub.dev/documentation/dropdown_search/latest/dropdown_search/DropdownSearch/DropdownSearch.html). You can use it to get the selected item.
Eg:

```
    DropdownSearch<UserModel>(
      label: "Name",
      onFind: (String filter) => getData(filter),
      itemAsString: (UserModel u) => u.userAsStringById(),
      onChanged: (UserModel data) {     <----- THIS ONE
         //Do something with this data
         },
    )
```

Comment: How can I implement this method in my code above?

Comment: Can we simply take the 'data' variable and assign it to another variable to then upload to firestore?

Comment: @AadirajAnil instead of `UserModel data` you can use `String value`. This `value` is the selected dropdown value.

Comment: When I answer this, I think there was no code part in the question